# Creating an "Add new item" button on SharePoint 2010

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm creating a SharePoint site and would like some help. On my homepage I would like a button where someone can click to add information and upon clicking the button I'd like for a modal window to open up. After the window opens it should prompt people to input information and save it onto a list somewhere in the background. I have done some google searching and couldn't find this. So far I tried this javascript which I found on google but I couldn't seem to get it to work. You will see the javascript below, and below that you will find an imgur link to better show what I am trying to accomplish.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9a3fC.jpg

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function OpenNewForm() {
        var listName = 'MyListUrl';
        var options =
        {
            url: L_Menu_BaseUrl + "/Lists/" + listName + "/EditForm.aspx?ID=1&IsDlg=1",
            dialogReturnValueCallback: Function.createDelegate(null,newFormClosedCallback)
        };

        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
    }

    function newFormClosedCallback(result, target) {
        if (result === SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) {
            SP.UI.Notify.addNotification("List item was added.", false);
        }

        if (result === SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel) {
            SP.UI.Notify.addNotification("Add new item was cancelled.", false);
        }
    }
</script>
<input value='add a new item' type='button' onclick='OpenNewForm();' id='btnNewForm' />
```

Comment: Can you be more specific with why this code "doesn't work"? How are you using this script, are you referencing it in a jslink or a code snippet?

Comment: I put that code into a content editor and it makes the button but upon clicking that button it gives me a 404 error. I'm not sure why it does this. Now it could be because I'm not sure where I should be making the edits (i.e. where to put the the information for my list such as the list's name and URL). If it works than I'd be happy to use it but I'm not all too sure where I should be editing.

Comment: You can put the list anywhere you want. The button just needs to redirect to the editform.aspx for that list.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Do I need the URL for the list or the name of the list? How do I link the desired list to this code?

Answer (score 0):

The example code that you provided will work. You just need to make some minor changes to reference your list. Also, this code references the editForm.aspx, and if you are wanting to add information you need the newForm.aspx.

```
     function openNewForm() {
        var listName = 'DisplayTitleOfYourList';
        var options =
        {
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/Lists/" + listName + "/NewForm.Aspx",
            dialogReturnValueCallback: Function.createDelegate(null,newFormClosedCallback)
        };

        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
    }

    function newFormClosedCallback(result, target) {
        if (result === SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) {
            SP.UI.Notify.addNotification("List item was added.", false);
        }

        if (result === SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel) {
            SP.UI.Notify.addNotification("Add new item was cancelled.", false);
        }
    }
<input value='add a new item' type='button' onclick='openNewForm();' id='btnNewForm' />
```

Depending on how your site and pages are set up, you may not be able to execute javascript directly from content editor or script editor web part. I always recommend linking javascript to a page using JS Link because I feel that it is much cleaner and easier to manage. See these posts for  more info:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93627/the-xss-auditor-refused-to-execute-a-script-in-from-chrome-when-using-scri

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/98583/javascript-in-content-editor-web-part-not-working-after-publishing-the-page[Javascript not working in web part](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/98583/javascript-in-content-editor-web-part-not-working-after-publishing-the-page)

[https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/119018/how-do-you-use-js-link-with-pages](http://Using%20JS%20Link)

Comment: Thank you Alex, I'm going to give this a try! Do I need to put the list's URL or Title anywhere in this code?

Comment: If the list is on the same site (not sure of your site hierarchy), then using the above code you will only need to supply the Display Title of the list where i have  `var listName = 'DisplayTitleOfYourList'`. Or, you can hardcode the full List url.

Comment: Perfect, and once again thank you so much for your help.

Comment: If my answer was helpful please remember to upvote :) Thanks and good luck